# Thuja hedge burnt, will it regrow?

Tags: trees, hedge, damage

Very devastated as my thuja hedge burned-out very badly. It was 25 years old hedge planted by myself from small cuttings. [image: picture shows only a small part of the hedge]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CYmSE.jpg)

What steps I should take to hope for it to come back? Would trimming burnt-out branches help? How hard should I trim it back.
Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 2):

I have thujas which was severely damaged by a storm (more than the half of the top cut off, splitting in the trunk). I only removed broken parts.

After **years** they recovered to such a degree that most people will not notice they have ever been damaged.

I suggest to wait about a year to see how they recovers. Then you can better decide how to prune them for a full restoration.

If you can identify any completely dead parts now, then I would remove them immediately to bring more light to the remaining parts.